# Python attribute button error

Tags: python, button, tkinter, attributes

Hey guys im just trying to create a simple button gui (absolute n00b ) 
but i can seem to figure out whats wrong with my code:

```
``__author__ = 'Isaac'

from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
""" My smart board application"""
def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
#Button1
    self.button1 = Button(self, text = "Calandar")
    self.button1.grid()

#button2
    self.button2 = Button(self)
    self.button2.grid()
    self.button.configure(text = "Weather")
root = Tk()
root.title("Smartboard")
root.geometry("500x400")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

the error im getting is:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/Isaac/Desktop/Useful     python/Clanadar/GUIOOP.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Isaac/Desktop/Useful python/Clanadar/GUIOOP.py", line 25, in <module>
app = Application(root)
File "C:/Users/Isaac/Desktop/Useful python/Clanadar/GUIOOP.py", line 11, in __init__
self.create_widgets()
File "C:/Users/Isaac/Desktop/Useful python/Clanadar/GUIOOP.py", line 20, in      create_widgets
self.button.configure(text = "Weather")
AttributeError: Application instance has no attribute 'button'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

thanks for your help

Comment: You have `self.button1` and `self.button2` but not `self.button`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your "#button2" comment;3 lines below, you used

```
    self.button.configure()
```

However there is no variable called "button". I think you meant to say:

```
    self.button2.configure()
```

Comment: such a simple mistake i can't believe i missed it